# Given a non-empty list of strings each of which represents a date, return the two dates in it that are closest to each other

Tags: java

The date in each string is expressed like "30/3/17@11:30 pm"; i.e. one or
    two digits for the day followed by a slash followed by one or two digits
    for the month followed by a slash followed by 2 or 4 digits for the year.
    The time has one or two digits for the hour followed by a colon followed
    by exactly two digits for the minute followed by one space followed by
    am or pm in upper, lower, or mixed case. The date and time are delimited
    by the @ character.

```
The return is a chronologically sorted list of two date objects. If any of
the incoming strings is invalid, return null. And if the list has more than
one pair of dates that are equally close, return the pair that occurs first.
```

Example: if the given list is:
    [30/3/17@11:30 pm, 31/12/2016@11:10 PM, 1/4/2017@6:00 am, 8/8/2016@12:00 aM, 1/1/2017@5:45 AM, 31/3/17@4:30 aM]
    then the return would be the list:
    [Thu Mar 30 23:30:00 EDT 2017, Fri Mar 31 04:30:00 EDT 2017]

Comment: So you got this problem to solve. You should start with it, of course you can come here to ask if you have any problem, but don't copy-past your task here, and ask the community to solve it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there is no direct java component to address your problem.
Its better to convert your Date Times to [java.util.Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) and Write a logic from there rather than dealing with strings.

java.util.Date class has following methods which you can use to build a logic.

```
boolean after(Date when)
```

Checks if the invoking Date object is later than the specified date.

```
boolean before(Date when)
```

Checks if the invoking Date object is earlier than the specified date.

```
int compareTo(Date date)
```

Compares the invoking Date object with the specified date and returns 0 if the two values are equal, negative value if the invoking object is earlier than the specified date and positive value if the invoking object is later than the specified date.

```
 boolean equals(Object date)
```

Check if the invoking Date object and the specified date are equal.

Refer [here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/date/java-util-date-example-how-to-use-date/) more details